# Passing arry of custom objects then applying to textView the array variables

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-activity, textview

I am starting to learn java and android developement and got stuck with passing a custom array from my MainMenu activity to another activity used to print out the values. Can anybody point out where I went wrong?

MainMenu Class:

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity{

    SharedPreferences sharedVar;
    Controller controller = new Controller();
    int size = 100;
    Sati[] sati = new Sati[size];
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
        sharedVar = this.getSharedPreferences("Var", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

    }
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        for(int i = 0;i<size;i++) {
            if (sati[i] != null){
                controller.upisiSmjenu(sati[i],sharedVar.getLong("Datum dolaska",0),sharedVar.getLong("Datum odlaska",0),sharedVar.getLong("Razlika",0));
            }
        }

    }
    public void otvoriUnosLayout(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, UnosSati.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void otvoriPregledLayout(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PregledSati.class);
        intent.putExtra("Sati",sati);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

UnosSati Class(used for data entry):

```
public class UnosSati extends FragmentActivity {

    SharedPreferences   sharedVar;
    TextView            txtRazlika;
    Sati                sati;
    Long                razlika;
    Date                dateD,dateO;
    int                 danD,mjD,godD,SD,MD,danO,mjO,godO,SO,MO;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.unos_sati);
        sharedVar = this.getSharedPreferences("Var",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        sati = (Sati)getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Sati");
        dateD = new Date();
        dateO = new Date();



        txtRazlika = (TextView) findViewById(R. id. txtRazlika);
        razlika = 0L;
        txtRazlika.setText(String.valueOf(razlika));

        danD    = sharedVar.getInt("DanD",0);
        mjD     = sharedVar.getInt("MjD",0);
        godD    = sharedVar.getInt("GodD",0)-1900;
        SD      = sharedVar.getInt("SD",0);
        MD      = sharedVar.getInt("MD",0);

        danO    = sharedVar.getInt("DanO",0);
        mjO     = sharedVar.getInt("MjO",0);
        godO    = sharedVar.getInt("GodO",0)-1900;
        SO      = sharedVar.getInt("SO",0);
        MO      = sharedVar.getInt("MO",0);

        dateD.setDate(danD);
        dateD.setMonth(mjD);
        dateD.setYear(godD);
        dateD.setHours(SD);
        dateD.setMinutes(MD);

        dateO.setDate(danO);
        dateO.setMonth(mjO);
        dateO.setYear(godO);
        dateO.setHours(SO);
        dateO.setMinutes(MO);

        razlika =((dateO.getTime() - dateD.getTime())/60000)/60;
        txtRazlika.setText(String.valueOf(razlika));


    }
    public void vratiNaGlavni(View view){
        sharedVar.edit().putLong("Datum dolaska", dateD.getTime()).commit();
        sharedVar.edit().putLong("Datum odlaska", dateO.getTime()).commit();
        sharedVar.edit().putLong("Razlika",razlika).commit();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainMenu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void otvoriKalendarDolaskaLayout(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Datum_dolaska.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void otvoriSatDolaskaLayout(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Sat_dolaska.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void otvoriKalendarOdlaskaLayout(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Datum_odlaska.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void otvoriSatOdlaskaLayout(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Sat_odlaska.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }



}
```

PregledSati Class used for viewing the data:

```
public class PregledSati extends AppCompatActivity {


    TextView textView1,textView2,textView3,textView4,textView5,textView6;
    Date dateD,dateO;
    String printD,printO,printR;
    Sati[] sati;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pregled_sati);

        dateD = new Date();
        dateO = new Date();
        printD = printO = printR = "";

        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R. id. txtIspis1);
        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R. id. txtispis2);
        textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R. id. txtispis3);


        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        Sati[] sati = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Sati");
        for(int i = 0;i<100;i++){
            textView1.append(String.valueOf(sati[i].getDateDolaska()));
            textView1.append("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Sati class:

```
public class Sati implements Parcelable{

    public long dateDolaska, dateOdlaska,ukupnoVrijeme;


    public Sati() {
        super();
    }

    public Sati(Parcel dest) {
        this.dateDolaska=dest.readLong();
        this.dateOdlaska=dest.readLong();
        this.ukupnoVrijeme=dest.readLong();
    }

    public long getDateDolaska() { return dateDolaska; }
    public void setDateDolaska(long dateDolaska) {
        this.dateDolaska = dateDolaska;
    }
    public long getDateOdlaska() {
        return dateOdlaska;
    }
    public void setDateOdlaska(long dateOdlaska) {
        this.dateOdlaska = dateOdlaska;
    }
    public long getUkupnoVrijeme() {
        return ukupnoVrijeme;
    }
    public void setUkupnoVrijeme(long ukupnoVrijeme) {
        this.ukupnoVrijeme = ukupnoVrijeme;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeLong(this.dateDolaska);
        dest.writeLong(this.dateOdlaska);
        dest.writeLong(this.ukupnoVrijeme);
    }

    public static final Creator<Sati> CREATOR=new Creator<Sati>() {
        @Override
        public Sati createFromParcel(Parcel dest) {
            return new Sati(dest);
        }

        @Override
        public Sati[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Sati[size];
        }
    };


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is because you have to get an array of Parcelables and be sure that class Sati is Parcelable.

```
Sati[] sati = getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra("Sati");
```

Comment: In this case it gives me this error:                                          Incompatible types.                                                                       Required:
gregov.toni.radnisati.Sati[]
Found:
android.os.Parcelable[]

Comment: Try to cast to Sati[]: 
Sati[] sati = (Sati[]) getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra("Sati");

Comment: Thank you had to remove the first "Sati[]:" but it solved the problem.